# Shoving Scrapy Objects into array when parsing; what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, scrapy

I've basically created a spider that follows a set of links acquired from an API, and then extracts text from the HTML body.  I'm trying to append returned items to appropriate lists, which are then added to a dictionary.  When I run the code, the resultant JSON file only successfully writes the first line.

I am running Python 3.6 in a virtual environment on a Windows 10 64-bit machine, and I run pip-upgrade daily.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import smtplib
from time import sleep # To prevent overwhelming the server between connections
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import scrapy
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import sys
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint
import json
import re


conn = mariadb.connect(user=dbuser, password=dbpassword, database=dbdatabase)
c = conn.cursor()

e = sys.exc_info()[0]

c.execute("Select URL FROM [TABLE]")
JobURLs = c.fetchall()
for object in JobURLs:
    urls = []
    url_string = str(object)
    rx = re.compile('\W\W\W$')
    res = rx.sub('', url_string)
    rx = re.compile('^\W\W')
    url = rx.sub('', res)
    urls.append(url)

c.execute("Select JvId FROM [TABLE]")
JobIDs = c.fetchall()
for object in JobIDs:
    item = {}
    item['JvId'] = []
    JobID_string = str(object)
    rx = re.compile('\W\W\W$')
    res = rx.sub('', JobID_string)
    rx = re.compile('^\W\W')
    JobID = rx.sub('', res)
    item['JvId'].append(JobID)

class JobListing(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'JobListingCrawler'

    start_urls = urls

    def parse(self, response):
        # pass
        item['urlText']     = response.url
        page_html           = response.body
        page_soup           = soup(page_html, 'lxml')
        for script in page_soup(['script', 'style']):
            script.extract()
        item['jobDescText'] = page_soup.get_text('''\n''', strip=True)
        ## TextCleaner Function for Word Counter
        text        = item['jobDescText'].replace('\n', ' ')
        lines       = [line.strip() for line in text.splitlines()]
        chunks      = [phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split(' ')]
        def chunk_space(chunk):
            chunk_out = chunk + ' '
            return chunk_out
        text        = ''.join(chunk_space(chunk) for chunk in chunks if chunk).encode('utf-8')
        try:
            text    = text.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        except:
            print(e)
            pass
        text        = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z,+3]', ' ', str(text))
        text        = text.lower().split()
        stop_words  = set(stopwords.words('english'))
        text        = [word for word in text if not word in stop_words]
        wordCounter = Counter(text)
        item['wordCounter'] = str(wordCounter)
        ## And now we parse for email addresses!
        prog        = re.compile(r"[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,}")
        found       = prog.search(item['jobDescText'].replace('\n', ' '))

        try:
            item['email']   = str(found.group(0))
        except:
            item['email']   = 'null'
            pass


        filename = 'results.jl'
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + '\n'
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            f.write(line)
        self.log('Saved Line to %s' % filename)
```

Comment: does parse get called multiple times? if so, the 'w' in the file open context will overwrite what was written before, you could try 'a' if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I amended the file saving portion of the script to amend ('a') but it seems to still only push the first result.  :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So silly me: I put the list variable within the For Loop, so each time the actions looped it would delete the previously written values.  Moving them outside of the loop solved the problem.

```
c.execute("Select URL FROM CareerOneStopJobs")
JobURLs = c.fetchall()
urls = []
for element in JobURLs:
    url_string = str(element)
    rx = re.compile('\W\W\W$')
    res = rx.sub('', url_string)
    rx = re.compile('^\W\W')
    url = rx.sub('', res)
    urls.append(url)

c.execute("Select JvId FROM CareerOneStopJobs")
JobIDs = c.fetchall()
item = {}
for JobID in JobIDs:
    item['JvId'] = []
    JobID_string = str(JobID)
    rx = re.compile('\W\W\W$')
    res = rx.sub('', JobID_string)
    rx = re.compile('^\W\W')
    JobID = rx.sub('', res)
    item['JvId'] = JobID
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare a [Scrapy Item](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html), which contains yours returned fields definion.

After that, just need to config your setting file to allow [Scrapy Feed Exports](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exports) using the built-in [JsonItemExporter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#jsonitemexporter) for your extract data:

```
FEED_URI: file:///tmp/export.json
FEED_FORMAT: json
```

Comment: So how would I go about that?  Something like this?

inline'
ITEMS.PY

    import scrapy
    
    class [SPIDER]crawleritem(scrapy.item):
        item['urlText'] = scrapy.Field()
        item['jobDescText'] = scrapy.Field()
        item['wordCounter'] = scrapy.Field()
        item['email'] = scrapy.Field()'

Comment: Ugh, pardon the duplicate comment; I cannot edit after 5 minutes and doing code markup seems impossible.

Comment: Just append your scraped data into Item object and return it on `parsed()`. Then the config of FEED_URI, FEED_FORMAT will help on exporting data to json instead of manual writing in your spider :)